# Linear Layouts not obeying weighting

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I have two vertical linear layouts which I want to use to occupy roughly a third and two thirds of the screen respectively. I am using layout_weight to achieve this but they are both remaining at 0dp thickness rather than occupying the available width of the parent.

To my understanding these layouts, when set to 0dp thickness, should occupy 
`layout weighting / total weighting`worth of the weight. This is, however, not happening.

Here is my xml, the first layout contains an ImageButton and the second is empty:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/silhouette" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the parent of these two linear layouts ? It should be linear layout with orientation vertical. Also width/height of child linear layouts is 0 depending on preferred orientation

Comment: @Satya So they have to be inside of another vertical linear layout for weighting to work?

Comment: yes, please check my answer

Comment: Can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this layout(Vertical Orientation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/silhouette" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>
```

For horizontal orientation

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/silhouette" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>
```